# Wireless Sensor Network Lifetime Estimation

Tags: energy, lifetime

I am attempting to replicate a calculation for estimating the lifetime of a wireless sensor network based on the measured energy draw of each operation.  These values are given in a table which I have screenshot-ed and attached below.

[image: summary table]

There are two types of motes and two configurations.  The first type of mote is a weather sensing mote that has all of the subsystems in the table but the occupancy sensing subsystem.  There is also a burrow mote that has every subsystem.  The weather mote has a single 2.8V 860mAhr battery.  The burrow mote has a single 3.6V 1Ahr battery.  Both motes can be in either a single hop or multihop configuration.  Energy draw based on overhearing or packet forwarding is ignored.

The period in the table is how often the activity occurs in seconds.  So the single-hop configuration climate senses and occupancy senses every 300 seconds.  The multihop senses every 1200 seconds.

I am attempting to determine how the 140, 127, 90 and 80 day lifetime estimates were reached.

My reason for asking is that I am producing a model of sensor network, and I want to put the measured energy estimates into the model.  After I have filled in the energy estimates, I want to write a program that can evaluate the model to determine the expected lifetime.

More or less I need the formula for determining the expected lifetime.  I hope I have provided enough information but I am not familiar with electric units of measurement.  If any needed details are missing, I'll edit the question to provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the "Weather mote" that has an average power consumption of $$717·10^{-6}W$$

It is powered by a 2.8 V battery and therefore its average current consumption will be $$I=\frac P V=\frac {717·10^{-6} W} {2.8 V}\approx 0.256 mA$$

Because the battery capacity is \$860 mA·h\$ the battery time will be: $$t=\frac {860 mA·h} {0.256 mA}\approx 3358 h=140 days$$

The other estimates can be calculated following the same steps.